# How many spears or javelins can a hero reasonably carry unencumbered?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, equipment, encumbrance

As an example, let's say that the hero is a Half Orc with a strength score of 20. They are wearing Chainmail armor, their main weapon is a two-handed glaive, and on their back they can carry spears or javelins.

How many **spears** or **javelins** could this orc could possibly carry, on top of the chainmail and glaive's weight?

Comment: 300 is not an answer, just a random number. Do you use the variant rules for determining encumbrance? Do your 'unencumbered' means carrying not more than 5 times your STR as the variant encumberance rules? Or you mean 'not heavily encumbered' (less than 10 times STR)?

Comment: Could you specify whether you are using the variant rules (Encumbrance) or not (PHB p. 176)?

Comment: Are we assuming the javelins are all bundled together / in a container, or is the awkwardness of carrying dozens of loose objects a factor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## You could carry *a lot* based on standard rules

Page 176 of the Player's Handbook states the following:

> **Carrying Capacity.** Your carrying capacity is your Strength score multiplied by 15. This is the weight (in pounds) that you can carry, which is high enough that most characters don’t usually have to worry about it.
>
> **Push, Drag, or Lift.** You can push, drag, or lift a weight in pounds up to twice your carrying capacity (or 30 times your Strength score). While pushing or dragging weight in excess of your carrying capacity, your speed drops to 5 feet.
>
> **Size and Strength.** Larger creatures can bear more weight, whereas Tiny creatures can carry less. For each size category above Medium, double the creature’s carrying capacity and the amount it can push, drag, or lift. For a Tiny creature, halve these weights.

You have a strength score of 20, which would give you a [carrying capacity](https://5thsrd.org/rules/abilities/strength/#lifting-and-carrying) of 300 pounds.
Taking into account that your two-handed glaive weighs 6 pounds, your chainmail armor weighs 55 pounds, each javelin weighs 2 pounds, and each spear weighs 3 pounds, we can do the math.

With the glaive and chainmail equipped, you could carry **119 javelins** or **80 spears** *separately*. If you wanted to carry both, you could carry **59 javelins** and **39 spears** *together*.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: It may also help to include that there may be confusion because the rules only talk about weight - they don't talk about how you'd carry that weight. In addition, you may want to include answers for the different encumbrance rules.

Comment: Yes, I wonder from a DM perspective, would you allow a character to walk around with 100 javelins and still be able to hide in shadows?

Answer (score 3):

Many groups tend to ignore encumbrance but they are the only rules that would specifically limit the amount carried.  Page 176 of the Player's Handbook says carrying capacity is strength multiplied by 15 so a character with a strength of 20 can carry 300 pounds of gear.  The armor, weapons, and equipment lists specify the weight of each item.  Total up the amount he's already wearing and carrying, subtract from his total carrying capacity, then divide by 2 (the weight of a javelin) or by 3 (the weight of a spear).

Since the rules for encumbrance are rather cumbersome, the best solution is probably to just make your own house rule and say that 2 or 5 or 10 or whatever of them can reasonably be strapped together and carried without causing problems.  Since the paladin class has 5 javelins as an option for starting equipment you might want to just apply that number.  There is really no need to carry a large amount since thrown weapons are not single-use and can be retrieved after the fight.

Any discussion of carrying javelins would not be complete without mentioning the Quiver of Elhonna which has a compartment that can hold 18 javelins.   It is a magic item listed in the DMG.